# How to do a service call for 'POST' method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to do a service call for 'POST' method for the payload with the headers described below?

Payload for the service:

```
{
  "SupplierPOPrint": {
    "ErrorFlag": "Status Code: 20, Message ID: 505",
    "ResultMessage": "Integration Service: Unable to find a routing corresponding to the incoming request message."
  }
}


headers: { "Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "text/xml", },

function poPrint() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/wps/proxy/http/10.249.114.31:8009/soa-infra/resources/Supp‌​lierPortal/CreateSup‌​plierPOPrintService!‌​1.0/CreateSupplierPO‌​PrintService/Create'‌​,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(updatedTemplate),
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(poPrintData) {
      console.log("poPrintData", poPrintData);
      poPrintDetails = poPrintData.SupplierPOPrint;
      console.log("poPrintDetails", poPrintDetails);
      poPrintTemplate = generatepoPrint(poPrintData);
      $("#poPrintOutput").html(poPrintTemplate);
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log("Update Content Failed", data);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "text/xml",   
          },

Comment: function poPrint() {
        $.ajax({
          url: '/wps/proxy/http/10.249.114.31:8009/soa-infra/resources/SupplierPortal/CreateSupplierPOPrintService!1.0/CreateSupplierPOPrintService/Create',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          data:new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(updatedTemplate),

Comment: crossDomain: true,
          success: function (poPrintData) {
            console.log("poPrintData", poPrintData);
            poPrintDetails = poPrintData.SupplierPOPrint;
        console.log("poPrintDetails",poPrintDetails);
   poPrintTemplate = generatepoPrint(poPrintData);
         $("#poPrintOutput").html(poPrintTemplate);
          },
          error: function (data) {
            console.log("Update Content Failed", data);
          }
        });
    }